# How do I print a string to the system console?

Tags: java

I've spent the last three hours trying to write a "string" to the "console"?

```
System.in.writeToConsole("\"string\"");
```

Comment: Why would you try System.**in** to **out**put anything?

Comment: Have you considered reading a Java tutorial? Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html for starters.

Comment: Because I want to write *in* the console, not *out* of it.

Comment: I suggest thinking of it is writing out to the screen from your application, rather than writing "inside" a console. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should look into **system.out**. I think you are confused the [in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in) and [out](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out), please read the link before and [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).

Comment: +1. This is the only answer here I think actually *earned* an upvote (for guiding toward the answer instead of providing it) - at least *my* only upvote. Nice choice. :)

Comment: @KenWhite thank you, we will see if the OP manage to pick up.

Answer (score 3):

It is `System.out.println("\"string\"");`

Comment: It might have been better to treat this as an educational opportunity, and guided the asker toward finding an answer instead of just giving it to them. This was obviously a "homework" type question, and you've just played "please do my homework".

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("\"string\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below

```
System.out.println("\"string\"");
```

Answer (score -1):

So you know about stdin, stdout, and stderr?

- System.in reads from stdin;
- System.out writes to stdout;
- System.err writes to stderr.

Then you have methods like print and println, print will write whatever you give it, println will write whatever you give it with a newline character at the end.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend to use some logging framework instead. Writing to console is a bad practice.